# Grails: How do you unit test a command object with a service injected into it

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, service, command-objects

I am trying to test a Controller
that has a Command object with data binding.

The Command Object has a Service injected into it.

But When I try test the command object the injected service method
is never found as it is never "injected"

Is there a way to mock a service inside a command object?

**Test method**

```
void testLoginPasswordInvalid() {
    mockRequest.method = 'POST'
    mockDomain(User, [new User(login:"freddy", password:"realpassword")])
    mockLogging(UserService) // userService mocked
    MockUtils.prepareForConstraintsTests(LoginCommand)

    def userService = new UserService()
    def user = userService.getUser("freddy")//Gets called and returns the mockDomain
    assert userService.getUser("freddy")//Passes

    def cmd = new LoginCommand(login:"freddy", password:"letmein")
    cmd.validate() // Fails (userService is nevr injected)
    controller.login(cmd)
    assertTrue cmd.hasErrors()
    assertEquals "user.password.invalid", cmd.errors.password
    assertEquals "/store/index", renderArgs.view
}
```

The getUser() method of the userService isn't found

```
Cannot invoke method getUser() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getUser() on null object
```

**Code**

The login method of the controller being called,

```
def login = { LoginCommand cmd ->
  if(request.method == 'POST') {
     if(!cmd.hasErrors()){
       session.user = cmd.getUser()
       redirect(controller:'store')
     }
     else{
       render(view:'/store/index', model:[loginCmd:cmd])
     }
  }else{

    render(view:'/store/index')
  }
}
```

The Command Object has a "userService" injected into it.

The validator calls this userService to find a user

```
 class LoginCommand {

    def userService

    String login
    String password

    static constraints = {
      login blank:false, validator:{ val, cmd ->
          if(!cmd.userService.getUser()){
             return "user.not.found"
          }
      }
 }
```

The userService.getUser() looks like this.

```
class UserService {

    boolean transactional = true

    User getUser(String login) {
        return User.findByLogin(login)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Service injection is done using Spring autowire-by-name. (Grep the Grails source tree for `autowire` to find a nice code fragment you can use to get it to autowire your controllers for you in integration tests.) This only functions in integration tests, where there's a Spring application context around that has the beans that can be injected.

In unit tests, you have to do this yourself since there's no Spring-land surrounding your stuff. This can be a pain, but gives you some benefits:

1) It's easy to inject mock versions of services - for example, using an `Expando` - in order to more closely specify the behavior of your controller's collaborating services, and to allow you to test only the controller logic rather than the controller and service together. (You can certainly do the latter in a unit test as well, but you have the choice of how to wire it up.)

2) It forces you to be explicit about the dependencies of your controller - if you depend on it, your tests will show it. This makes them a better specification for the behavior of your controller.

3) You can mock only the pieces of external collaborators your controller depends on. This helps your tests be less fragile - less likely to need to change when things change.

Short answer: your test method needs a `cmd.userService = userService` line.

Answer (score 8):

What John says is on the mark.  One example might be:

```
def mockUsers = [new User(login:"freddy", password:"realpassword")]
mockDomain(User, mockUsers)

def userService = [getUser:{String login -> mockUsers[0]}] as UserService

def cmd = new LoginCommand (/*arguments*/)
cmd.userService = userService
```

You can lookup other ways to mock objects at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Mocks